# If/Else statement in Katalon Studio

Tags: katalon-studio

I'm try to do this statements but not successful. Can anyone help me. Thank you alot

```
if (WebUI.verifyTextPresent('Nhân viên hiện không rảnh trong khung giờ này', true) {
    WebUI.waitForAlert(2)

    WebUI.click(findTestObject('Page_Trang Qun L (1)/FailConfirm'))

    WebUI.closeBrowser()
} else {
    WebUI.waitForAlert(3)

    WebUI.click(findTestObject('Page_Trang Qun L (1)/ThemButton'))

    WebUI.waitForAlert(2)

    WebUI.click(findTestObject('Page_Trang qun tr SkyAdmin/button_OK'))

    WebUI.waitForAlert(2)

    WebUI.closeBrowser()
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not successful'? Do you have any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of the `WebUI.verifyTextPresent()` says if the first parameter is a regular expression.

See https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/%5BWebUI%5D+Verify+Text+Present.

I do not speak your language, but the text doesn't seem like a regex. 
Try changing `WebUI.verifyTextPresent('Nhân viên hiện không rảnh trong khung giờ này', true)` to `WebUI.verifyTextPresent('Nhân viên hiện không rảnh trong khung giờ này', false)`.

Comment: Thank you but it's not work. I try to verifyTextPresent() in if/else statement. If text presents anywhere in the page source, the browser must close. But if/else statement in this case is not work.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe Katalon doesn't recognize all the characters. Maybe you could try to verify this part of the text: 'nh trong khung gi'?